# Is this speed for cpu fan normal?

Tags: overheating, cpu-cooler

I am kinda worried about the temperatures my laptop heats up these days and which leads to overheating and finally an insecure shutdown.
here is a screenshot of speedfan values....
[image]

Comment: 178 RPM?? Most PCs won't even boot unless it's doing 1000. None of those temps ought to kill anything, but management is off somewhere; either the fan speed reading is wrong, or the fan's not working properly

Comment: my gpu goes to 95*c just before shutdown...

Comment: @Tetsujin you mean these temperatures are normal but fan speed is not?

Comment: If it runs to shutdown & the fan is still doing 200RPM... then the readings could well be correct - but you need confirmation; visual will do if the fan really is going that slowly

Comment: how to visually confirm?I mean I observed the fan to be more silent after giving it to service(official) last time